# Give a two-point form for the line through $P(1, 3)$ and parallel to $v = (5, 4)$

Tags: linear-algebra

My assignment is asking me to give a two-point form for the line through $P(1, 3)$ and parallel to $v = (5, 4)$.

I'm aware that the two-point form is $x(t)=(1-t)p+tq$, and the question has given me one point $P(1, 3)$. Thus, so far I have $x(t)=(1-t)(1, 3)+tq$.
But how can I find the second point $q$ if they haven't given it to me?

Comment: If the line is parallel to $(5,4)$ then $(1,3) + k(5,4)$ will be another point on the line for any $k$.  So choose something easy like $k=1$ to get another point like $(1,3)+(5,4)=(6,7)$.  That's your second point.

Answer (score 1):

The line is
$$(x, y)=(1, 3)+t(5, 4)$$
with $t\in\mathbb{R}$

If $p=(x_1, y_1)$ and $q=(x_2, y_2)$, then $(x_1, y_1)=(1, 3)+t_1(5, 4)$ and $(x_2, y_2)=(1, 3)+t_2(5, 4)$.

Then

\begin{align*} 
x(t) &= (1-t)(x_1, y_1)+t(x_2, y_2)\\
     &=(1-t)((1, 3)+t_1(5, 4))+t((1, 3)+t_2(5, 4))\\
     &=(1, 3)+t_1(5, 4)-t((1, 3)+t_1(5, 4))+t((1, 3)+t_2(5, 4))\\
     &=(1, 3)+t_1(5, 4)-tt_1(5, 4)+tt_2(5, 4)\\
     &=(1, 3)+((1-t)t_1+tt_2)(5, 4)
\end{align*}

Comment: I realize that, but that's in point-parallel form. The question specifically asks for the two-point form.